# Convergence of negative geometric series in the p-adic integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, p-adic-number-theory

In real analysis, I am learning about convergence of series in metric spaces. My professor states that in the metric space of $\mathbb Z$ with the $2$-adic metric, one of the series converges and the other does not:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)^n$$

I know that the first series converges to $-1$, so his claim is that the latter series does not converge. However, this series is Cauchy and $\lim_n (-2)^n=0$, and I am under the impression that this implies the series converges in the $2$-adics.

Comment: This rather depends on what $p$ is.

Comment: Yes... Sorry, this is in the 2-adics. I've edited my question

Comment: A sequence of integers $(a_n)_n$ converges in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ iff for every $k$, $(a_n \bmod p^k)_n$ converges (stabilizes). It is from this fact (definition) that you obtain your criteria (that $a_{n+1}-a_n \to 0$)

Comment: I think that "in the metric space of $\mathbb Z$ with the $2$-adic metric" both series diverge. (They converge only in the **completion** of this metric space.)

Comment: Pierre: but the first series converges to an element of $\mathbb Z$ (namely $-1$), so i think it does converge in the metric space. However, the later series may not and I am trying to figure out how to prove this.

Comment: I deleted my earlier answer, which was wrong. The second series converges in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The limit in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ of the second series is $1/(1+2) = 1/3$ which is not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @4e554c4c -You're right, and I was wrong. Sorry! (If you want me to be notified of your comments, please insert an `@Pierre` in the comments.)

Comment: @hunter - I suggest that you correct your answer and undelete it.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these series definitely converge in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. As you say, the sequences of partial sums are both Cauchy.

However, the second series converges to an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ which is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}$; namely, $1/3$. To see this, use the old geometric series trick:
$$
\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{1 - (-2)} = 1 + (-2) + (-2)^2 + \ldots
$$

Comment: (more formally, $1 + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^n \to  1/(1-x)$ p-adically for any $x$ which is divisible by $p$, because $(1-x)(1 + \ldots + x^n) = 1 - x^{n+1} \to 0$.)

Comment: thank you! This is what I was looking for. I'm going to have to look into the power series some more.